# for a particular click remove the tick mark from check box and use red color inside checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

- If I click third time the small check box should turn into red color and tick mark should not show inside the text box.instead of tick mark inside the check box it should show red color inside the check box.
- can you tell me how to fix it.
- providing my code below.

  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sq2q93?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

  ```
  public open(event) {      
    // attach event to button
    this.count = this.count + 1;
    console.log('this.count--->' + this.count);
    if (this.count % 3 == 0) {
      // apply new style
      console.log('multiple of 3--->' + this.count);
      this.multipleOf3 = true;
    } 
    else {
      this.multipleOf3 = false;
    }
  }
  ```

Comment: if you don't want to show checkbox after 3rd click - then hide it; right now you're just painting label with red, so do also hide the checkbox or whatever else..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Checkboxes` can not be styled. You would need a third party js plugin and there are many available. ( like this one http://icheck.fronteed.com/ )

But if you want to do this yourself it basically involves hiding the checkbox and creating an element and styling that as you want, then you display it or hide it whenever the `checkbox` is checked or not.

in your case, you can either create an element next to the checkbox, style it and hide it, then display it whenever you add the `.multiple-of-3` class, 
or simply hide the `checkbox` in `multiple-of-3` class like so ( according to the example you provided in the link ) :

**app.component.html**

```
<label [ngClass]="{'is-multiple-of-3':multipleOf3}">
  <span id="redSquare"></span>
  <input type="checkbox" name="rememberLogin" id="buttonId"  (click)="open()"> click me
</label>
```

**app.component.css**

```
/* if you want to create an element on top of the checkbox */
#redSquare{
  width: 13px;
  height: 13px;
  background: red;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: -16px;
  z-index: 99;
  position: relative;
  left: 4px;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.is-multiple-of-3 #redSquare{
  visibility: visible;
}

/* if you want to simply hide it */
.is-multiple-of-3 checkbox{
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: hey can you tell me how this code is working "{'is-multiple-of-3':multipleOf3}"   so that in future I can fix it myself

Comment: sure, this is a shorthand `if statement`, it's like `if(multipleOf3 == true) then display 'multiple-of-3'` , `multipleOf3` is a variable and `display` means putting it between the quotes and therefore adding the class to the element.